# As x approaches infinity, why does $ \lim_{x \to \infty}\arctan \left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Just wondering why the following is true!
$$\lim_{x\to \infty }
\arctan\left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean limit of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right)$?

Comment: @Mufasa Yes!! Fixed

Comment: **HINT:** What is $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=?$

Comment: @Mufasa It's undefined, $x=\frac{pi}{2}$. What's the reasoning to to get to pi/2?

Comment: $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\infty$, therefore $\arctan(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. There are many angles whose $\tan$ will give you $\infty$, but $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the one in the first quadrant.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand @Mufasa

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if you consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x$ or the given limit, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-2}2=\infty$.

$\arctan x$ is the angle of the point $(1,x)$, which translates to the point on the unit circle
$$
\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}},\,\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)
$$
In the limit $x\to\infty$, this point tends towards $(0,1)$, which corresponds to the angle $\frac\pi2$.